# What are the external dependencies of a Python executable?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I guess there is a tool called Py2Exe to convert a Python application into an executable file. Since I am also using PyQt4 for GUI apps., what are the external dependencies for such an executable? What type of files I need to bundle along with my Setup? Is there any Python Setup Builder tool?

Comment: You might want to ask this on StackOverflow, since it's not about "programming" but specifically about Py2exe.  You also might want to check the FAQ's http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

> If you do have the rights to redistribute MSVCR90.dll, there should be a copy of it in your Visual Studio install, under VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT. Since Visual Studio 2008, you can't just copy this DLL file - you also need the manifest file that you'll find there.